# Get controller folder name in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

if i have folder in controller like this :

```
controller/folder/class/method
```

how to get current folder,

for class : `$this->router->class`

for method : `$this->router->method`

How can i get the folder name or full path ???

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [URI class manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

To get current uri:

```
$this->uri->uri_string()
```

To get controller folder in you example:

```
$this->uri->segment(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
controller/folder/class/method
```

Try it :

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);
```

It will display your foldername under controller

Ex :

```
/controller/stackoverflow/class/method

o/p : stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$this->router->fetch_directory()](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Router.php#L479)

From `system/core/Router.php`:

```
/**
 *  Fetch the sub-directory (if any) that contains the requested controller class
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
 function fetch_directory()
 {
     return $this->directory;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used:

```
$this->uri->segment(1)
```

To get my controller name. Not sure if this is the since you're looking for a folder name.